# unexpected string constant

Tags: r

I have a problem with my database. I want to enter the database in R, but appears this message
"error unexpected string constant".

I wrote this command: `read.csv(prova1,sep";", header=20)`

What's the problem? I suppose something in my database, but I don't know what it is.
Thank you for reply

Comment: Maybe sep = ";", not sep";"?

Comment: We are not clairvoyant, please make your example reproducible. Or at least show a snippet of your csv file.

Answer (score 6):

Like what was commented, you made a syntactic error, i.e. you forgot the `=` between `sep` and `;`.